# Using ACCOUNTS\sqlservice for linked server object user mapping

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I have a scheduled task on my warehouse server that runs a batch file, which triggers a command that runs a sproc on my SQL server. The task is set up to run as ACCOUNTS\sqlservice.

I recently made some updates to my linked server objects to avoid warehouse users querying data from them by mapping just the user(s) that should have query access in the linked server security. While mapping the local sql server login to sql server login works, I can't seem to map a domain account between the two servers successfully, that is, the ACCOUNTS\sqlservice, who has sa on both servers.

Any ideas on how I can give the sqlservice account access to query the linked server object? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One solution: use an appropriate alternative user for the remote mapping that is a local sql server login rather than a domain account.

There may be another way to do this between domain accounts, but haven't the time for that.